# How to send file with file name by use wifidirect?

Tags: filenames, wifi-direct, getopenfilename

I use wifidirect to send file,but I can't get the file name(include .jpg or .mp3),and sent it,it always null.
i'm using wifidirect demo provided Android Developers

I use

```
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
        fileName = f.getName();
```

and

```
final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + "Wifidirect" + "/" + fileName);
```

but `fileName` is alwas null

```
public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionInfoListener {

    protected static final int CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 20;
    private View mContentView = null;
    private WifiP2pDevice device;
    private WifiP2pInfo info;
    //private static WiFiDirectBundle bundle = new WiFiDirectBundle();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private static String fileName;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
                config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back to cancel",
                        "Connecting to :" + device.deviceAddress, true, true
//                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
//
//                            @Override
//                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
//                                ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).cancelDisconnect();
//                            }
//                        }
                        );
                ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).connect(config);

            }
        });

        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_disconnect).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).disconnect();
                    }
                });

        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                        // registered apps
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);                        
                    }
                });

        return mContentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // User has picked an image. Transfer it to group owner i.e peer using
        // FileTransferService.


        Uri uri = data.getData();
        File f = new File(uri.getPath());
        fileName = f.getName();
        TextView statusText = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        statusText.setText("Sending: " + uri);
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Intent----------- " + uri);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uri.toString());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
                info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
        getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        this.info = info;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // The owner IP is now known.
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.group_owner_text)
                + ((info.isGroupOwner == true) ? getResources().getString(R.string.yes)
                        : getResources().getString(R.string.no)));

        // InetAddress from WifiP2pInfo struct.
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText("Group Owner IP - " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());

        // After the group negotiation, we assign the group owner as the file
        // server. The file server is single threaded, single connection server
        // socket.
        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
            new FileServerAsyncTask(getActivity(), mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text))
                    .execute();
        } else if (info.groupFormed) {
            // The other device acts as the client. In this case, we enable the
            // get file button.
            mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text)).setText(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.client_text));
        }

        // hide the connect button
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the UI with device data
     * 
     * @param device the device to be displayed
     */
    public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        view.setText(device.deviceAddress);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText(device.toString());

    }

    /**
     * Clears the UI fields after a disconnect or direct mode disable operation.
     */
    public void resetViews() {
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * A simple server socket that accepts connection and writes some data on
     * the stream.
     */
    public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Context context;
        private TextView statusText;
        //String FileName = "bundle.fileName";


        /**
         * @param context
         * @param statusText
         */
        public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context, View statusText) {
            this.context = context;
            this.statusText = (TextView) statusText;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
                /*final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + "Wifidirect" + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ".jpg");*/
                final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + "Wifidirect" + "/" + fileName);

                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();

                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
                InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
                copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
                serverSocket.close();
                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                statusText.setText("File copied - " + result);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + result), "image/*");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            statusText.setText("Opening a server socket");
        }

    }

    public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);

            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: oh! I put all the code ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
        fileName = f.getName();
```

This part of code in your app will get executed - if device acts as client

and

```
final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + "Wifidirect" + "/" + fileName);
```

this part of code in your app will get executed - if device acts as server (in this case GO) but fileName is always null

Since filename is initialized to "null" , on the server device this will be null.

FileServerAsyncTask is created only on GO( server ) as per the code.

Comment: Thanks!!
I understand !!
^^

Comment: If u want to send a file with the fileName , first send the fileName to the server from client and then start transferring the file to the server.I am not sure if this is the only way , but I have done in this way for my app.

Answer (score 0):

In android sample code file transfer is working only from client to server. In this code user can do file sharing in both directions i.e client to server as well as server to client.

You can see this link.

[How can I transfer files between Android devices using Wi-Fi Direct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638335/how-to-transfer-files-between-android-devices-using-wifi-direct/31531931#31531931)